# Sequence numbers and Precision issues

Tags: c#

I have a sequence number which dictates the order things are done in, for example, a person scans items 1 - 15 then inside those items there is sub-components which I was going use decimal precision as I will no the whole number 15 and add a precision value on it to become 15.1

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        decimal sequenceNumber = 15;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            decimal output = sequenceNumber + Convert.ToDecimal((i));   
            Console.Write(output + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I have done a .net fiddle the result is not What I expect to be it is 15 16 17 but it should be is 15.1 15.2 15.3 but how do I do this using a foreach statement and not just a for loop instead as I am going over a List Collection

```
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
```

Here is my .net fiddle.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FwXt5h

Comment: `foreach (var item in listOfSomething) { /*stuff*/ sequenceNumber++; }`. What's in the list? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: the fied sequence numbers and it be 1-15 as expalined but say within 15 then 7 items they should become 15.1 ,15.2 etc i just need to no how to add the .1 .2 as a precision number instead of a whole number

Comment: So the collection stuff is just misdirection. OK. You can add `0.1m` to a decimal. You can increment a decimal value by `0.1m` on each time through the loop.

Comment: yes ed but how do i convert 0.1 when it in the loop it thinkgs its a whole number oh i think i get u now

Comment: Your question would be very much easier to read and understand if you would punctuate and capitalize your own sentences in a conventional way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about:

```
public class Program
{

  public static void Main()
  {
      decimal sequenceNumber =15;

      for (decimal i=0.1; i<1 ; i+=0.1)
      {
        decimal output = sequenceNumber +i;  
        Console.Write(output +"\n");
      }  


  }
}
```

Comment: +1, but Just for fun - a one-liner using linq: `Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => {Console.WriteLine(i / 10m + sequenceNumber); return i;}).ToList();`

Comment: @EdPlunkett Evolution of programming: write less code to do the same work for a higher price.